# Where should the button code be placed?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display a table with the values in the database. I would like to add a column to the table where a button can be placed such that it updates the database. Here is the php code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">.mui-textfield.mui-textfield--float-label > label {-webkit-transition:all .15s ease-out;-moz-transition:all .15s ease-out;-o-transition:all .15s ease-out;transition:all .15s ease-out;}</style>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
      href="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.5.3/css/mui.css">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="final.ico" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="new_style.css">
   <script src="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.5.3/js/mui.js"></script>
   <style>
      /* Add font-smoothing */
      html,
      body,
      input,
      textarea,
      buttons {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
      }
   </style>
   <style>
      a:link, a:visited {
      background-color: #ff0066;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 10px;
      text-align: center;    
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inl
      a:hover, a:active {
      ine-block;
      }
      a:hover, a:active {
      background-color: red;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <form method = "GET" action = "update.php">
      <body>
         <header class="mainheader">
         <div style="background-color:#d9d9d9">
            <nav>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="/" style="color:#FFF">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/loginProf.php" style="color:#FFF">Log-in</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
</body>
<center>
<h2> Attendance for Classroom 106 </h2>
<div class="table-responsive-vertical shadow-z-1">
<table class='mui-table mui-table--bordered'>
<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Attendance</th><th>Status</th><th>Mark Attendance</th></tr></thead><tbody>
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "root";
   $dbname = "attendance";

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }

   $sql = "SELECT pid, name, attendance, status FROM students";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Attendance</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
       // output data of each row
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "<tr><td>".$row["pid"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td> ".$row["attendance"]."</td><td> ".$row["status"]."</td><td><a href='update.php?uname=" .$row['uname'].'">update</a></td></tr>";

       }
       echo "</table>";
   } else {
       echo "0 results";
   }
   $conn->close();
   ?>
</div> <br><br>
<a href="loggedinProf.html"> Go back </a>
</center>
<input type = "submit" name = "update" value = "MarkAttendance"/></form>
</body>
</html>
```

The button should be added as the last column.
Here is the update.php code

```
<?php

require "init.php";
$attendance = $_POST["attendance"];
$uname      = $_POST["uname"];
$count      = $_POST["status"];
$query      = "UPDATE students SET attendance = ('$attendance' + attendance) WHERE uname = '$uname';";
$query1     = "UPDATE students SET status = ('$count') WHERE uname = '$uname';";
$result     = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$result1    = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
if ($result > 0 && $result1 > 0) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Also, you're not "printing" anything. You're displaying data from a database. What you're asking is a lot to code. Probably no  one is going to do that for you.

Comment: I edited the question. We tried different formats of placing buttons in the code, one of which is present in the posted code. We want somebody to modify the code such that there is  a valid display of button, because as of now it is not even displayed.

Comment: Okay, after your code update. Maybe you can create a separate page that contains a form. And When you click on the update button you should set a get parameter with the id of the record you want to update. Then you get the results in your form inputs from that page by the id from $_GET and to update ....hope you get the drill.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid display of button"? The update button is not showing and the other data in the table do?

Comment: We don't want it to be in another page. We want the button to be in the same page, inside the table.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. The button is ok placed as it is now.

Comment: Basically, after the button code is added, the table is not displayed at all. Otherwise it works fine. So, we wanted to know where exactly should the code be placed.

Comment: That's because you have an extra character in your code. Remove that and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
   echo "<tr><td>".$row["pid"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td> ".$row["attendance"]."</td><td> ".$row["status"]."</td><td><a href='update.php?uname=" .$row['uname'].'">update</a></td></tr>";
```

To this:

```
  echo "<tr><td>".$row["pid"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td> ".$row["attendance"]."</td><td> ".$row["status"]."</td><td><a href='update.php?uname=" .$row['uname'].">update</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Only few rows are dispalyed. In this case, only rows with odd indices. Also,being a beginner I am having trouble writing a php that takes the uname and updates the column. Could u modify the update.php as well?

Comment: For the update you should make use of the record id, because is unique. The "uname" can repeat in your database and your update won't work correctly. What do you mean by "only rows with odd indices"?

Comment: could u help us with update.php. The display looks fine now. But the database is not getting updated

Comment: Use var_dump to debug. Try it on your queries first and see what it returns. If returns false the problem lies in your query. Also very the $_GET and $_POST variables to see if they are empty or not.